# Related : get current store_view_id (scope_id) in magento2

Tags: magento2

so, i want to reset configuration value from admin form,based on current selected store_view. for that i need to get current store_view_id (scope_id).
your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

magento save storeview data in `store` table.

For set particular storeview configuration data, you need to get current store view id (store id).

```
protected $scopeConfig;

protected $_storeManager;

protected $_configWriter;

public function __construct(
        ...
        ...        
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
)
{

    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;   
    $this->_configWriter = $configWriter;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; 
    ...
}


public function execute()
{  

    $websites = $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
    $scope = "stores";             
    $store_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();        
    $value = 99; //set your value
    $this->_configWriter->save('sectionId/groupId/fieldId',$value , 'stores', $store_id);  
    return;

}
```

you can get all storeview ids with groups.

```
 public function getallstoreIds()
    {
      $groups = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getGroups();   
      $storeName = [];    
      $storeIds = [];
      foreach ($groups as $key => $group) {
         $storeName[] = $group->getName();             
         $stores = $group->getStores();
         foreach ($stores as $store) {
      $storeIds[$store->getId()] =  $store->getName(); // get store view name            
        }
    }  
    return   $storeIds;}
```

For Select storeview in adminarea.

```
protected $state;

protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->state = $state;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function resolveCurrentWebsiteId()
{
    if ($this->state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {


        $request = $this->_request;
        $storeId = (int) $request->getParam('store', 0);
    } else {
       
        $storeId = true; 
    }

   
    return  $storeId;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but i want  selected store view id (scope_id). 
for example : i have two store view with name A and B & id 1 & 2 . when admin select store view B i want to fetch its id (2).

Comment: do you need in admin area or frontend area.

Comment: I have updated anser use adminarea code.

Comment: $storeId = (int) $request->getParam('store', 0);
here , 0 for what ?

Comment: it is for default value.

vendor/maento/fframework/HTTP/Phpenvironment/Request.php

public function getParam($key, $default = null)

Comment: check getParam function /vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php::getParam function

Comment: thank you so much for the answer

Comment: Welcome. it would help you and others.

Comment: thats so kind of you